# How To Add Localstorage to List and Grid View When Clicked

Tags: javascript

I am finding it difficult to add localstorage functionality to this javascript below. So that it will retain the view the user chose.

Below codes are working perfectly well. I only want the functionality of Localstorage. Please help me.

HTML

```
<div class='KaXTamTampilan'>Style:
<div class='pilih'>
<input checked='checked' id='KaXTamTampilanGrid' name='view' type='radio' value='grid'/>
<label class='grid' for='KaXTamTampilanGrid'>Grid</label>
<input id='KaXTamTampilanList' name='view' type='radio' value='list'/>
<label class='list' for='KaXTamTampilanList'>List</label></div></div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#KaXTamTampilanGrid').click(function(){
$("body").removeClass('KaXTamTampilanList');
    }); 
$('#KaXTamTampilanList').click(function(){
$("body").addClass('KaXTamTampilanList');
    });
```

I have the Css in place. I only need to modify the javascript codes to have localstorage function. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

I assume your have event listeners on the radios, so you need to trigger a click.
If not, you can just toggle the class

```js
$(function() { // on page load

  var list = localStorage.getItem("KaXTamTampilanList") || "";    // get choice or nothing
  // $("body").toggleClass('KaXTamTampilanList', list === "yes"); // if trigger is not needed
  if (list==="yes") $('#KaXTamTampilanList').trigger("click");    // if trigger IS needed

  $('#KaXTamTampilanGrid').click(function() {
    $("body").removeClass('KaXTamTampilanList');
    localStorage.setItem("KaXTamTampilanList", ""); // "clear" choice
  });
  $('#KaXTamTampilanList').click(function() {
    $("body").addClass('KaXTamTampilanList');
    localStorage.setItem("KaXTamTampilanList", "yes"); // save choice
  });
});
```

Comment: What I actually mean is that, at default List is checked but display is in Grid. But when you choose your style of view, it works and save to Localstorage but List is always checked even when you choose Grid and reload. The HTML is in my real post @mplungjan

Comment: This is the HTML ```<div class='KaXTamTampilan'>Style:
<div class='pilih'>
<input checked='checked' id='KaXTamTampilanGrid' name='view' type='radio' value='grid'/>
<label class='grid' for='KaXTamTampilanGrid'>Grid</label>
<input id='KaXTamTampilanList' name='view' type='radio' value='list'/>
<label class='list' for='KaXTamTampilanList'>List</label></div></div>```

Comment: I see that in your question. I trigger the click so it should change. I do not understand the problem you describe

Comment: Ah, perhaps you mean `else $('#KaXTamTampilanGrid').trigger("click");` ???

Comment: your previous code works. The place you added the else condition is not working. Please revert it back to your old code. I know where to place the else condition that worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I have edited your answer to the codes you first gave me that worked perfectly fine which I included the else condition. Thank you so much for your help. It worked perfectly well now without issues.

Comment: No need to edit my code,. I just moved the testing to the top and removed the else

Answer (score 0):

Store the style value in `localStorage` and assign value in `document.load`.

```
$('#KaXTamTampilanGrid').click(function(){
  $("body").removeClass('KaXTamTampilanList');
  localStorage.setItem('style', 'style1');
}); 

$('#KaXTamTampilanList').click(function(){
  $("body").addClass('KaXTamTampilanList');
  localStorage.setItem('style', 'style2');
});

// initialization
$(document).load(() => {
  let style = localStorage.getItem('style');

  if (style === 'style2') {
    $("body").addClass('KaXTamTampilanList');
  } else {
    $("body").removeClass('KaXTamTampilanList');
  }
});
```

Refer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: It is likely not enough. See my answer

Comment: @mplungjan I think we are doing the same thing except I am doing the `getItem` in document.load .. right ?

Comment: Not completely. I trigger a click if needed. Also I add the event handlers to page load too

Comment: I am ALSO performing the getItem in `document.load` - shorthand: `$(function() {})`

Comment: Yes.. $(function() {}) = $(document).ready(). Good to know. Thanks @mplungjan

Comment: @Aditya-Bhave thanks for your answer, but mplungjan understands me better and answered me correctly. Thanks to you all

Answer (score -1):

Try with localStorage

```
  $('#KaXTamTampilanGrid').click(function(){
var userChoice = $('#KaXTamTampilanGrid').val();
localStorage.setItem('userChoice', userChoice);
$("body").removeClass('KaXTamTampilanList');
    });
```

And for the other input

```
  $('#KaXTamTampilanList').click(function(){
  var userChoice2 = $('#KaXTamTampilanList').val();
    localStorage.setItem('userChoice2', userChoice2);
$("body").addClass('KaXTamTampilanList');
    });
```

Comment: And then what. You now just saved it but not restoring it. Also it is not the value they want to save

Comment: First why you downvote my answer ? second he can retreive the data (localStorage.getItem('userChoice')) , my answer was clear : help them to I only want the functionality of Localstorage

Comment: He already knew he could use localStorage, you are not showing how to re-activate the choice after loading the page

Comment: I believe you need to grasp the underlying idea of what OP is trying. You are not setting  or triggering the user choice here. Just storing it.

Comment: May be I didn't understand the question correctly , you can edit my answer

Comment: Why do nothing ? my goal is to help

Comment: I meant - not interact with my answer. In any case if you do not understand the issue, then having me edit your answer is the same as me just pointing at my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199889/discussion-between-ahmed-rebai-and-mplungjan).

Comment: @ahmed-rebai The display always go back to Grid after a reload while List is checked. And at default, List is always checked. Please help me fix this issue

Comment: @VictorKachi please check  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58076515/5330655 this answer more helpful

Comment: @aditya-bhave The display always go back to Grid after a reload while List is checked. And at default, List is always checked. Please help me fix this issue

Comment: @mplungjan wow it worked but there is one problem. LIST is always checked. Please can you modify your code so List won't be checked when not active? Thanks so much